# Get user Locale on script

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I´m having a little problem. I am using gmap in primefaces and we need to load the script

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"/>
```

However I need to load the script according to the language of the user Locale.

How can I manage to do that without "hardcoding" the string?

I tried something like this :

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;language="#{template.userLocale} type="text/javascript"/>
// {template.userLocale} has a string o the locale
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've there a HTML syntax error. What you end up getting would look like this given a language of `en`:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;language="en type="text/javascript"/>
```

*(rightclick page in browser and do View Source to see it yourself)*

You need to move the doublequote to the end of the attribute value:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;language=#{template.userLocale}" type="text/javascript"/>
```

So that the HTML will end up to be:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;language=en" type="text/javascript"/>
```

EL can just be used in template text. You need to realize that JSF basically produces HTML code. The HTML `<script src>` attribute and the EL `#{}` doesn't run in sync. Instead, JSF/EL procuces it and you just need to make sure that the resulting HTML is syntactically valid.

Comment: it was a rookie mistake. Thanks BaluscC